# Edit an array of char*

Tags: c, string, char

I have an array of `char *` like this:

```
char * gradient_xpm[] = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

I need to change the value of those strings.

I've tried `strcpy` and the `=` operator, but it gives me a Segmentation Fault.

e.g:

```
strcpy(gradient_xpm[1],"jkl");
gradient_xpm[1][2] = 'x';
```

I wasn't able to edit even a single char. How can I edit those values?

Comment: This is really more C than C++. That's terrible C++ practice.

Comment: +1 @DeadMG but maybe he needs to use C libraries that accept C strings?

Comment: @EitanT that's what `.c_str()` is for.

Comment: @KillianDS not if you need to pass a modifiable `char` array to that function (I'm not defending this practice, I'm just saying that it might have another reason to it).

Comment: @EitanT, Still not really a reason to use C in the first place. Just copy it over first.

Comment: @EitanT even then you're usually better of copying a `std::string`'s content in a char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have string constants in your array, and those can't be changed. This is the cause of your segfaults.

You'll need to setup your array without using string constants, then copy the string constants into your array.

Something like:

```
char *gradient_xpm[3];

gradient_xpm[1] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STR_LEN + 1));
strncpy(gradient_xpm, "jkl", MAX_STR_LEN);

// now this will work:
gradient_xpm[1][2] = 'x';
```

Similarly for `gradient_xpm[0]`, `gradient_xpm[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying string literals in C is undefined behavior. So anything can happen, not necessarily a segfault.

From the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 6.4.5 String literals 6.4.5/6:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify string constants, which are marked as off-limits. You can, however, modify memory you've allocated on the heap or stack. That said, if you're using C++, consider using arrays of [the `string` class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), instead of managing `char *` arrays. The memory management issues are much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented this using string literals and you cant change them

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit the contents - that's a bad, BAD idea. In some compilers, that'd be a compile-time error, as string constants are `const char *`, as opposed to `char*`.

Instead, flip the pointer:

```
gradient_xpm[1] = "jkl";
```